# undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class - where's the error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now but I can't see the error.

When I go to `jobs/new`. Instead of seeing the form that I specified in my view. I'm receiving - `undefined method model_name' for NilClass:Class`

Here's my controller where im defining the new action.

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :json

  ...

  def new
    @jobs = Job.new
    respond_with @jobs
  end
```

And my view.

```
<%= form_for(@jobs) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :name %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :client %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :client, rows: 6%>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

And my model.

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client
end
```

The source of the error is line 1 according to the error message in my browser.  But I can see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: What do you want to put to `client` field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work but has no sense :)

```
def new
  @jobs = Job.new
  @jobs.client= CLient.new
  respond_with @jobs
end
```

What do you want to put into your `client` textarea?

Comment: Fixed it on my own :) I changed the `@jobs` text in my view to `:jobs` and it worked!

But thank you for your response :)